Can I power my esp32 and motor from a single rechargeable battery?
I'm in desperate need for help with designing my circuit. I'm very new to electronics and I wanted to make a circuit with a motor driver that sits under an esp32. The esp32 sends commands to the motor driver to run a small motor and led. The esp32, motor driver, led, and tiny motor are all being powered from the same rechargeable battery. The circuit needs to be powered while the battery is being charged. Everything works perfectly but after a while the components on the esp32 are burning to the touch and it no longer accepts new code uploads.
I've done a lot to troubleshoot like placing diodes, capacitors, and voltage regulators but the end result is the same. I feel like there's just something fundamental to circuit design that I'm missing. If anyone can shine a light on any potential issues, it would be a huge help. I also understand the way I did it is not with the best components, right now I'm just trying to understand the issue to learn more about electronics in general.
Here is a link to where I purchased the esp32:
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B08D5ZD528?ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_fed_asin_title&th=1
My circuit is being powered by this rechargeable battery. The circuit needs to be on while the battery is plugged in or removed from charging. Its output rating is 7.4-8.4V/2A. It's powering both the esp32 and the motor driver/motor.
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0CQ2HNRXL?ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_fed_asin_title&th=1
For my motor driver I chose the L293D. This is the datasheet for it:
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/l293d.pdf?ts=1729560099170&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FL293D
The motor driver can power two motors and can support moving them in both directions. However, I only need one motor so I connected one side to a red/green led and the other side to a small motor here:
Motor Link
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B09DG3GCGK?ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_fed_asin_title





Hi, I added all of the schematic images there are. I place the esp32 on top of the pcb I made and solder the power pin to the circuit. The esp32 and motor driver are powered by the 7.4-8.4V 2amp battery. Like every major component on the esp32 becomes hot, the wifi antenna and the esp32 chip especially.
